# Tailwind - Struggling to align form fields correctly

Tags: tailwind-css

I have some search params above a table. I want everything to be on one line with the search and filter fields on the left and button to create new pulled all the way to the right. Any thoughts on how to do this? Here is a tailwind play of what I have so far.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/fHMprfAuNW

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex class on your form **"flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center"**

On the children items use :
***flex-1*** for your reserch bar to get all the freespace.
**flex-none** for you other items to get auto width

Add some media queries to get full width (breakpoint in this example is md)

https://play.tailwindcss.com/oQe2L4Kt8s